# Incomplete code with Elvis operator and addition in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, operators

I am learning Kotlin and I happened to write this:

```
 var nullTest: Int? = null
 println(nullTest?++ ?:0)
```

Trying to compile and run, I get the "incomplete code" error. Same with:

```
 var nullTest: Int? = null
 println(nullTest?+1 ?:0)
```

While if I use:

```
var nullTest: Int? = null
println(nullTest?.inc() ?:0)
```

It compiles and runs correctly. Why is that so? Why do I have to use .inc() and can't I just use the + operator?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nullTest?.inc()` works because `?.` is an operator: the [safe-call operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls), which calls the following function only if the value is not null.

`nullTest?++` doesn't mean anything in Kotlin, because `?` on its own doesn't mean anything; there's no lone `?` operator.  (Also, `++` needs to follow the name of a variable or property it can increment.  Similarly, `+` needs to be between two values.)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use "++" incrementation and "--" decrementation on non nullable variables. Same rule to operators like "+", "-", "/", "*", etc.

If you have nullable variable you have to use translated methods like ".plus()", ".minus()", ".div()", ".inc()", ".dec()", with '?' before dot of course.

Comment: More info about translated methods here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#property-delegation-operators

Answer (score 0):

The safe call operator in Kotlin is represented as `?.` and is not referenced in any other manner. The Elvis operator works similar to a `!= null` check but will resolve to the right side if the left is null similar to how

```
val thing: Int? = null
val other: Int = 42

val new: Int = if (thing != null) thing else other
```

One of the ways to make it easier to understand this, is it all comes down to function signatures at the end of the day. From [Kotlin Functions](https://zetcode.com/kotlin/functions/#:%7E:text=A%20function%20signature%20is%20a,parameters%2C%20and%20the%20return%20type.)

> A function signature is a unique identification of a function for the Kotlin compiler. The signature consists of a function name, its parameters, and the return type.

Any operator function such as the `+`, `++`, or `-` has a correlated function name, but is a special syntax for writing that function reference.
[Operator Function Overloads](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#increments-and-decrements)

The operator overload functions don't have a syntax for handling the safe null call before themselves being called. The safe call may only be called on a `.` operator.

From your example

```
var nullTest: Int? = null
println(nullTest?+1 ?:0)
```

If we need an operation and the null check, we would have to do like I showed above with the if statement, otherwise we have to split the operations to multiple lines

```
var nullTest: Int? = null
var backup = 0

// This adds one to the values regardless of if it was null or not
val ourValue = (nullTest ?: backup) + 1

// Uses safe call operator to only increment the nullable value
val otherValue = nullTest?.inc() ?: backup

println(ourValue)
println(otherValue)
```

Or we can do this with an `if` and only add one to the potentially null value

```
var nullTest: Int? = null
var backup = 0

// Only adds one to the nullable value
val ourValue = if (nullTest != null) nullTest + 1 else backup

println(ourValue)
```